# pythonでリストをCSV出力する際に、不要なカンマが入ってしまうのを入らないようにしたいです。

Tags: python, csv, google-analytics-api

GAのレポーティングAPIから数値を取得し、それをCSVで出力したいと考え、
下記のような関数をPythonで書きました。

```
"""GAから集計するための関数"""
def get_results(service, profile_id):
  # Use the Analytics Service Object to query the Core Reporting API
  # for the number of sessions within the past seven days.
  return service.data().ga().get(
      ids='ga:' + profile_id,
      start_date='7daysAgo',
      end_date='today',
      dimensions='ga:date',
      metrics='ga:sessions').execute()

"""集計した結果を表示する関数"""
def print_data_table(results):
  output = []
  for header in results.get('columnHeaders'):
    output.append('%s' % header.get('name'))

  if results.get('rows',[]):
    for row in results.get('rows'):
        output.append('%s' % row)

  print(output)

  f = open('output.csv','wt')
  Writer = csv.writer(f,lineterminator='\n')
  Writer.writerows(output)

  f.close()
```

上記の関数で数値を取得すると、

```
g,a,:,d,a,t,e
g,a,:,s,e,s,s,i,o,n,s
[,',2,0,1,5,0,6,0,5,',",", ,',1,',]
[,',2,0,1,5,0,6,0,6,',",", ,',2,',]
[,',2,0,1,5,0,6,0,7,',",", ,',3,',]
[,',2,0,1,5,0,6,0,8,',",", ,',4,',]
[,',2,0,1,5,0,6,0,9,',",", ,',5,',]
[,',2,0,1,5,0,6,1,0,',",", ,',6,',]
[,',2,0,1,5,0,6,1,1,',",", ,',7,',]
[,',2,0,1,5,0,6,1,2,',",", ,',8,',]
```

というように出力され、不要なカンマが入ってしまいます。
Pythonのcsvモジュールの仕様書を見てみたのですが、
どのように記述すれば、カンマが取れるのかわかりません。

解決策をご教示いただけませんでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします！

Comment: 元データがどういう形式で、出力データがどうなってほしいのかを記載してください。「GAのレポーティングAPIから数値を取得」というのでは元データが分かる人が限られてしまいます。

Comment: 典型的なミスなので元データがなくてもわかります。スカラー値である文字列をリストとして扱うとこうなりますね。`"abc"`を`list("abc")`とすると`["a","b","c"]`になるアレです。

Comment: CSVよりも、`print(output)`の時点でデータ構造がおかしいです。

Answer (score 4):

結果から逆にたどると`get_results`の値は次の通りだったはず。

```
{
  "columnHeaders": [
    {"name": "ga:date"},
    {"name": "ga:sessions"}
  ],
  "rows": [
    ["20150605", "1"],
    ["20150606", "2"],
    ["20150607", "3"],
    ["20150608", "4"],
    ["20150609", "5"],
    ["20150610", "6"],
    ["20150611", "7"],
    ["20150612", "8"]
  ]
}
```

であれば次のように書けば動きます

```
def print_data_table(results):

  header = [h.get('name') for h in results.get('columnHeaders')]
  output = [header] + results.get('rows',[])

  print(output)

  with open('output.csv','wt') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(output)
```

CSVの内容

```
ga:date,ga:sessions
20150605,1
20150606,2
20150607,3
20150608,4
20150609,5
20150610,6
20150611,7
20150612,8
```

Comment: ご回答いただき、ありがとうございます！
本当に初歩的なミスですね。。
list()の理解がうまくできていませんでした。

実装してみたら、うまく出力できました！
本当にありがとうございました